# SQL Server Express issue deploying MVC4 application to IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

I've spent the past two days going through google (and here) with different variations of a connection string on my deployment server...  If I had hair left, I'd have pulled it out by now... ;)

I have an application that runs perfectly on my development Win7 box and am working on deploying it to a test server before I put it into beta.

The test server is Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.

I'm able to deploy the application to IIS and the site comes up.

But when I got to a page that connects to the SQL Server Express running on the local host, it dies. I should also mention that the database is already existing on the SQL Server Express instance and my Winforms and service application works great when connecting to that database.

My `web.config` contains the following connection string:

```
<add name="OIDEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.OID.csdl|res://*/Models.OID.ssdl|res://*/Models.OID.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OID;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The error I get is:

> *The underlying provider failed on Open.*

I've tried resetting the service in SQL Server to `nt authority\network service` (to match the app pool). I've also tried creating a SQL Server user and using the following connection string:

```
<add name="OIDEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.OID.csdl|res://*/Models.OID.ssdl|res://*/Models.OID.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OID;User ID=OID_User;Password=MyPrivatePAss;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I've gone into the SQL Server configuration manager and configured / enabled named pipes then TCP/IP and used the host IP to connect through server= in the connection string.

I am able to log into SQL Server Management Studio with the username/password and also using the IP vs. the instance name of `.\SQLExpress`.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried using machinename\sqlexpress?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well...

Answer (score 0):

ok, it only took 3 days to figure this out... I added the following code to my error.cshtml: 
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ActionName)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ControllerName)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Exception.Source)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Exception.InnerException)

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Exception)`

This showed me that the IIS APPPOOL\[PoolName] did not have access.  I added this into my SQL config with the following instructions: [Add IIS 7 AppPool Identities as SQL Server Logons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons)