# How AppPoolIdentity access remote SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, security, iis, application-pool

I was able to get [Application Pool Identity](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) to work properly, I even was able to get it to access remote SQL Server database successfully. I documented the steps in [an answer to another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35130264/249336).

Still, all applications hosted in the same machine are able to access the remote database, which makes sense as I add the SQL Server account with machine name `<My Domain>\<My Machine>$`, not account name.

Now, my question is: how to allow only a certain application to access the remote database, not any application on the machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can't using Application Pool Identity accounts. If you want to allow only specific applications to access the database you need set the application pool identity to a Managed Service Account or a domain account. Managed Service accounts were introduced in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. There is an advantage on using Managed Service Accounts: you don't need to manage its password, however there is no GUI to manage them.

Here you have an article introducing to to Managed Service Accounts:

[Introducing Managed Service Accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560633(v=ws.10).aspx)