# Error when trying to create new Login user for SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to follow the procedures described in this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons) but if I enter 
 IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName as the login name (as in step 3) it throws an error saying that it is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters. I'm using SSMS for SQL 2012.

UPDATE: Just to clarify: The "Invalid character" error was b/c I was trying to enter the user    on "SQL Server Authentication" when it must be "Windows Authentication".

Comment: I dont understand what is `b/c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is some sample TSQL code from one of my blogs to create a login and user.  http://craftydba.com/?p=656

It does not like the .  Put in in brackets. []

```
-- Delete existing login.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'BSA_USER')
DROP LOGIN [BSA_USER]
GO

-- Add new login.
CREATE LOGIN [BSA_USER] WITH PASSWORD=N'M0a2r0c9h11#', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[BSA]
GO

-- Delete existing user.
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'BSA_USER')
DROP USER [BSA_USER]
GO

-- Add new user.
CREATE USER [BSA_USER] FOR LOGIN [BSA_USER] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Change the syntax for a Windows Account.

```
-- Using users naming ...
CREATE LOGIN [APPPOOL\MyAppPool]
FROM WINDOWS
WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [MyDatabase]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the msg after I executed your script: Msg 15006, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
'IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool' is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters.

Comment: Please see above, if windows account, add FROM WINDOWS.  I gave you a code snippet above, Please try again.

Comment: I got his error : Windows NT user or group 'LAPTOP-N48A3H8V\AspNetCore' not found. Check the name again.

Answer (score 3):

Ben answered his own question:

> UPDATE: Just to clarify: The "Invalid character" error was b/c I was
>   trying to enter the user on "SQL Server Authentication" when it must
>   be "Windows Authentication".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when creating a Windows domain user in SSMS.

This solved it:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f084029-b0cf-4e7d-bb07-a11e31363660/tsd03072-xxxxxxx-is-not-a-valid-name-because-it-contains-invalid-characters?forum=vstsdb

**Synopsis:**
The error message is misleading, the error case is that the for the situation where you have a Windows login and the (userName != loginName). The code does not take casing into consideration right now, so they have to be an exact match.