# Page not redirecting on login vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

Using VS 2013 and SQL Server 2014. (VB)

I have a simple login pop up window where a user enters their username and password and clicks OK.  They are then redirected to another page if that username and password is found in the database.  I have two users set up in the DB for testing.

The process is carried out by the two variables being passed to the DB through linq to a stored procedure.

If I run it locally, as in debug in VS then it works as expected.  If I then try from the web (hosted at home) it doesn't work.  There are no errors messages etc it just doesn't work.

Am I missing something fundamental?

UPDATE

I believe its down to the app pool of the website not having access to the associated database.

Comment: Post the code. We can't really help you unless we can look at what you have.

Comment: this fixed my issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons

Answer (score 0):

When you try to host the application where it doesn't work have you configured iis for form validation? Defaults to anonymous access by default. More information about does not work would be helpful.