# asp.net app on IIS can't connect to localdb

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have an asp.net web app running on IIS, and everything is fine, until I try to access the database I get this error: [image]

I have read the 2 parts of the Using LocalDB with Full IIS: [1 Part](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/) | [2 Part](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/)

I followed the instructions and still get the error, is there a way to check that I have followed the steps correctly?

Is there anything else I can check for that may be causing this error?

Note: I tryed this with asp.net and asp.net core applications, the core one doesn't give any description at all so I am testing this with asp.net. The database that I am using is the one that visual studio provides. If you would like me to provide any further information ill be happy to, I have been stuck with this issue for a while now and can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Can you access your localdb through SSMS? Is tcp/ip enabled in SQL Server configuration manager?

Comment: Please check this criteria [sqlmusings](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

Comment: @gofr1 I can Connect to the database using SSMS, however the configuration manager is giving me and error 'invalid namespace'

Comment: Please, try solution from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2382/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-connect-to-wmi-provider/)

Comment: Alright so I arrived at a 'ok' solution for asp.net is it didn't publish the .mdf file and didn't have full permission (read/write) to the wwwroot folder. Of-course there is still no connection to the actual database.

Comment: @gofr1 Thank you, in SQL Native Client -> Client Protocols, TCI/IP is Enabled

Comment: @AntonToshik that is nice! Can you also check in Config Manager if SQL Server Browser and SQL Server Agent are working?

Comment: @gofr1 It doesn't display any services at all in the configuration manager

Comment: Weird... Are you sure there is an SQL Server installed and running on your machine?

Comment: @gofr1 Isn't some kind of sql server express get installed when Visual Studio is installed?

Comment: As far as I remember there was some option in VS setup that allow to install SQL Server, but I am not sure about it. The last time I installed VS 2015 I already got SQL server installed on my machine.

Comment: Based on msdn VS install SQL Server Data Tools component by default, no info about full server.

Comment: @gofr1 I restarted the machine and I'm getting "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'." error. I can see the account in SSMS security and it has read and write properties.

Comment: @AntonToshik here I can advice to take a look at that [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication/) to understand how to login to SQL server from IIS properly. What user accounts are used based on IIS auth settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns it's not too complicated, but my inexperience with both IIS and Databases made it confusing. Hopefully this can help someone in the future. There might be some minor steps/tweaks I missed out but that's because the whole solution took a while to setup.

1. Make sure you have SQL Server actually installed. You can download the 2008 version which I used [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695). Can be a pain to setup and I actually messed up when installing, [here is the vid I watched](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0YYYu4yYsI) (I didn't install: Database Engine Services).
2. Next you want to make sure the IIS identity (IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 in my case) has permission to connect to the Database server. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons).
3. Once it has connected to the database server, it need's to be able to connect to a database on the server (I didn't know that a database and a database server are 2 different things). You need to do something simular to **Step 2**, in SSMS expand the databases folder, and select the database you which to grant access too, there is a security folder in there as well and you want to add the Identity to that folder.

Other useful points:

- If your sql configuration manager isn't opening please [tell it to](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2382/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-connect-to-wmi-provider/), thank you gofr1. This is a very useful tool for checking up on your database connection (as it turns out)
- Make sure you setup your connectionString to point to the sql server. Make sure it doesn't connect to the mdf file with `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\your_database_name_here.mdf` located in the connectionString.
- For asp.net Core read the documentation it [is god](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html), as the errors are non-existent once the app is deployed on IIS it will help in dark times. Always check `publishOptions`.

To further help you understand how the whole process works, thank you to gofr1
[read here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication/). Didn't solve the issue but [worth a read](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile/).

Might include more stuff in here later if I remember I missed anything out.

Comment: I having similar issue, but my SQL Configuration Manager is up, both Visual Studio and SSMS can connect to database and I do not using .mdf in connection string. The IIS Application Pools identity is correct and had been set to "Load User Profile" = True.

“system.applicationHost/applicationPools” -> applicationPoolDefaults -> processModel -> setProfileEnvironment had been set to True also.

Yet, the issue still persists.

Comment: Then I change the IIS Application Pools Identity to Local System, then change back to the Windows User, then recycle it, it works.