# Login failed for user '{domain}\{user}' SqlClient.SqlException in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When I deploy my app to a server, I'm getting the Login failed message. My DB and app are located on two separate physical machines. However this has not posed a problem when developing and testing locally and connecting out to the DB server; only after publishing.

[image]

**Steps I've taken To attempt to resolve**

1. In my Web.Config I've set Integrated security to false. When integrated security was true, it was giving the same error but with the machine name in place of the user name.
2. I placed valid credentials in the User ID: and Password: fields of the Web.Config. The credentials placed in Web.Config are also used to log into Sql Server Management Studio directly.
3. Within SSMS I've also verified those credentials will work under Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication.

Those credentials I've set in the app work when I log into the SSMS using Windows Authentication. Advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. create a .udl file in that pc to test connection string.
2. verify you firewall (not block port 1433 (default))
3. Verify your configuration in sql instance (network)

Comment: Make sure the user is `enabled` !

Comment: @M84 it gives `Login failed` error, so it passes firewall.

Comment: @AliAdlavaran sorry, you have right.

Comment: was it resolved @LifeOf0sAnd1s ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS runs your application under a local machine account. This account does not have any permissions to access your SQL Server. In order to achieve integrated security, you need grant it access. There are a few ways to do it, the thread [Add IIS 7 AppPool Identities as SQL Server Logons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons) will get you started.

Another way, which is preferred over adding the IIS account, is to create a service account in Active Directory and setting the App Pool Identity in IIS to the service account. Depending on your environment, you should work with your network admin and or DBA to set this up.

Your last option would be to simply use [SQL Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx).