# grant to SQL server: application pool or IUSR?

Tags: sql-server, iis, permissions, application-pool

I had problem in connection between SQL server and IIS. I found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons) . The accepted solution says that  `IIS APPPOOL\YourAppPoolName`  should be granted to the SQL server. However I have added a login to SQL server with name `NT Authority/IUSR` and in user mapping I mapped this login to the desired database and it works.

What is the difference between ApplicationPoolIdentity and IUSR identity? Is there any security or performance difference between IUSR or APPPOOL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IUSR account is per server, an ApplicationPoolIdentity is per application pool.

By giving the IUSR account access to your database, you give access to all websites from that server running under that acccount. When using an ApplicationPoolIdentity you give access per application pool/website.

So the difference is only in the granularity of the security.